# How to change Google form ID after copying?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I conduct online meetings everyday and get the feed back from students in google form. I use the copy menu to copy a form and create a new feedback form everyday. Now I am trying to use Google Script.
I use the following standard google script to  copy a google form template. **However the copied form has the same id.** I need to change the id of the copied google form so that it can be used everyday. How to change the ID of the copied form? **Note** :the forms collect email so if the form id is same, it doesn't allow students to enter data the next day with the same email (Says - data already entered)

```
// Open a form by ID and create a new spreadsheet.
var form = FormApp.openById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.create('Spreadsheet Name');

// Update form properties via chaining.
form.setTitle('Form Name')
    .setDescription('Description of form')
    .setConfirmationMessage('Thanks for responding!')
    .setAllowResponseEdits(true)
    .setAcceptingResponses(false);

// Update the form's response destination.
form.setDestination(FormApp.DestinationType.SPREADSHEET, ss.getId());
```

Comment: Note that
file.makeCopy(file, folder); too creates form with the same id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Two different files on Google Drive never have the same ID

- A file `id` is a unique identifier by which a file can be accessed, modified, shared and so on.
- An `id` cannot be manually changed and it is not necessary since the copy of your form will never have the same `id`.

**Your problem is a different one:**

- Your code does not make a copy of the form, it only creates a new destination spreadsheet.
- To make a copy of the exisitng form, you can implement for example:

```js
  var newFile = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz').makeCopy();
  var newFormID = newForm.getId();
  var newForm = FormApp.openById(newFormID);
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried making a copy using  file.makeCopy(file, folder) - as commented below my Original post, but I didn't make proper changes to main code so that function was never reached. Now its clear why the code failed. Thanks a lot.